# SELECT GROUP BY AND ORDER BY Sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Tenho duas tabelas Tb_Processo e Tb_Custas unidas pela chave NumeroProcesso. Preciso listas as informações da união delas ordenadas por status Urgência e DataPrazo. Sendo que quando for urgência devem ser listadas no top da lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo ordenar por data, da menor para maior ex: 11/04/2019, 14/04/2019, 16/04/2019

SQL:

```
    @AdvogadoID int,
    @TipoCustas nvarchar(9),
    @Numero int

SELECT  TOP (@Numero)        
        Processo.NumeroProcesso, 
        Processo.GCPJ, 
        Processo.ProcessoID,
        Processo.Natureza, 
        Processo.Valor, 
        Processo.Comarca, 
        Processo.Vara,
        Custas.CustasID, 
        Custas.Descricao, 
        Custas.AdvogadoID, 
        Custas.ValorCustas, 
        Custas.DataCustas, 
        Custas.Concluida,
        Custas.DataPrazo,
        Custas.TipoCustas,
        Custas.Urgencia

FROM    Processo INNER JOIN Custas 
ON      Processo.NumeroProcesso = Custas.NumeroProcesso
WHERE   (Custas.AdvogadoID = @AdvogadoID)
AND     (Custas.TipoCustas = @TipoCustas)

ORDER BY Custas.Urgencia DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caro amigo, peço desculpas caso não tenha entendido o problema e se minha resposta parecer inocente.
Não faltou apenas:

```
ORDER BY Custas.Urgencia DESC, Custas.DataCustas
```

Comment: ORDER BY Custas.Urgencia DESC, Custas.DataPrazo era simplesmente isso!

Comment: Que bom, espero ter ajudado.